# Filter data from two tables and display them on to a data gridview C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-express

if i have two tables such as books burrowed and books returned in sql .
ex;a person burrows 5 books A,B,C,D,E,F (this is stored in burrowed table)
then he returned 3 books A,B,E (this is stored in returned table)
how do i get the books he haven't returned (C,D,F) to a data grid view.
Can some one say me the code

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share your code if you have. This is not a code providing site..

Comment: Please provide table structures.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal,Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.